# Netflix Error "Unable to update EME"

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, netflix

System:

- Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
- Firefox 53.0.3 (32-bit) with 'Widevine Content Decryption Module provided by Google Inc.'

Done so far:

- disabled all of the other add-ons/plug-ins
- "Play DRM content" is checked (Preferences/Content)
- cleared Cached Web Content as well as Offline Web Content and User Date (Preferences/Advanced/Network)

And when I try to play a video on Netflix, I get:

> Whoops, something went wrong...
>
> Streaming Error
>
> Unable to update the EME.
>
> Error Code: F7363-1260

Unfortunatly I cannot get a 64-bit system anytime soon.
Does anyone know a fix to this? Haven't found this error anywhere else (the Error Code seems to describe different situations)

EDIT: Since Netflix only supports Mozilla Firefox and no others ("[Non-Mozilla builds are not supported.](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742)") I downloaded Firefox 53.0.3 32-bit for Linux from the official mozilla site, however I get the exact same error.
I tried also to spoof the user-agent to Chrome, which only changed to letter in the Error-Code from F to M, everything stayed the same
Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work on 32 bit since the very first Firefox update that made it work.  The next Firefox update broke it and it hasn't worked since. :(

Comment: Yea, that is indeed sad. Could it work with Pipelight/Silverlight tho?

Comment: The only thing I found to work was getting the last 32-bit Google Chrome and using that.  Decidedly not recommended from a security standpoint.

Comment: Seeing the same issue. Running FireFox 53.0.3 (32-bit)

Comment: Found this: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/watch-netflix-natively-linux-easy-way/ *Actually the reason Firefox doesn’t support native Netflix playback is due to the lack of EME support on the Linux version of their browser. Mozilla is an advocate and proponent of spreading the ideals of Open Source Software so including DRM inside of the HTML5 Standards would be a setback for the Open Source Community as a whole.*

Comment: @Twisty: I don't know "Firefox added support for the necessary DRM modules required to play Netflix (and other premium content) using HTML5 last year.

But it’s taken Netflix 7 months to flick the necessary on their end." (http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/netflix-finally-adds-support-firefox-linux as well as several others)

Comment: Going to download and test with FireFox 52 ESR.

Comment: @ChrisF agree. I been using Netflix in FireFox for a long time w/o Pipelight. I am surprised that it's no longer working.

Comment: No luck with ESR either. Same Error. Cleared cookies, cache, offline web files, and disabled all add-ons.